# Python - (PyGI) Как отобразить TreeView c ListStore используя glade?

Tags: python, gtk

Если создавать Liststore и TreeView с помощью Python, то все работает хорошо:

```
...
model = Gtk.ListStore(str, bool)

for name in data:
    model.append([name, True])

treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.model)

col_name = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name")
cell_name = Gtk.CellRendererText()
col_name.pack_start(cell_name, expand=False)
col_name.set_attributes(cell_name, text=1)

col_bool = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Bool")
cell_bool = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
col_bool.pack_start(cell_bool, expand=False)
col_bool.set_cell_data_func(cell_bool, render_icon)

treeview.append_column(col_bool)
treeview.append_column(col_name)
...
```

Но, если с использованием Glade:

```
...
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("ui.glade")

treeview = builder.get_object("treeview")
model = treeview.get_model()

col_bool = builder.get_object("col-bool")
cell_bool = builder.get_object("cell-bool")
col_bool.set_cell_data_func(cell_bool, render_icon)

for name in data:
    model.append([name, True])
```

Файл ui.glade

```
...
<object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore">
   <columns>
     <!-- column-name service -->
     <column type="gchararray"/>
     <!-- column-name state -->
     <column type="gboolean"/>
   </columns>
</object>
...
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="col-name">
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Service</property>
    <property name="expand">True</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cell-name"/>
      <attributes>
        <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
      </attributes>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="col-bool">
    <property name="max_width">25</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">State</property>
    <property name="alignment">1</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkCellRendererPixbuf" id="cell-bool"/>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
...
```

то при выполнении model.append получаю много ворнингов:

> (myapp:9434): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to
>   allocate widget with width -4 and height -9

и затем

> Ошибка сегментирования

Не могу понять в чем дело, вроде бы все правильно.

Так же если данные внести в GtkListStore в glade файл они отображаются вполне нормально.

Comment: Где объявление  "treeview" из файла ui.glade . Там прописано свойство  <property name="model">liststore</property> ?

Comment: @Yaroslav , да, конечно. Я же указал что если внести данные в модель прямо в glade в секции `<data>` и не выполнять append, то отображение происходит нормально.

Comment: А функция render_icon . Что делает ? Эта функция добавляется в ui.glade при инициализации TreeViewColumn ?

Comment: Устанавливает `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf` в `cell-bool`, разные иконки в зависимости от значения получаемого из модели.

Comment: В ui.glade нет соединения между колонкой (col_bool), ячейкой (cell_bool) и функцией render_icon , а в исходном коде есть такое соединение col_bool.set_cell_data_func(cell_bool, render_icon)

Comment: Ну как же нет? GtkCellRendererPixbuf находится непосредственно в теле GtkTreeViewColumn, а render_icon как раз для того чтобы из bool получить GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf. Если вам кажется что я пытаюсь установить в атрибут pixbuf этого cell-bool именно boolean из модели, то обратите внимание что секции `<attributes>` у этого cell нет, а значит значения из модели автоматически не передаются, а при формировании каждой строки вызывается колбэк установленный с помощью `set_cell_data_func(cell, func)`

Comment: В первом рабочем фрагменте кода видно вызов функции `col_bool.set_cell_data_func(cell_bool, render_icon)` Все работает. Но когда Вы используете Glade. В представленых фрагментов кода этого вызова функции нет.

Comment: Понял что вы имели ввиду. Да я пропустил в опубликованном фрагменте установку этой функции. Поправил.

Comment: Возможно у вас опечатка, но здесь `treeview = self.builder.get_object("treeview")` у вас ссылка с именем _treeview_, а здесь `model = self.treeview.get_model()` вы получаете модель от ссылки с именем _self.treeview_. Это ссылки на разные объекты.

Comment: Да, это опечатка, просто хотел для наглядности код упростить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял как точно избавился от ошибки. Как мне показалось, проблема в родительском `GtkScrolledWindow`, а именно в свойстве `resize_mode` (Режим изменения размера) если оно установлено в `immediate`.

```
<object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="resize_mode">immediate</property>
  <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
  <property name="min_content_width">350</property>
  <property name="min_content_height">250</property>
  <child>
    <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview">
      <property name="visible">True</property>
      <property name="can_focus">True</property>
      <property name="valign">start</property>
      <property name="model">liststore</property>
      ...
    </object>
  </child>
</object>
```

Ошибка сегментирования, только без warning'ов.

Comment: Я поэтому отказался от использование glade , очень много не документированных параметров в использовании Builder.